# Autorest code customization does not work

Tags: code-generation, openapi-generator, autorest

What i am doing wrong, when code customization does not work?

readme.md

```yaml
require: $(this-folder)/../readme.md
input-file: $(this-folder)/../../swagger/TaxManagementAPI/swagger.yaml
output-folder: ./Generated
csharp: true
namespace: TaxManagement.RestClient
```

MessageBaseTest.cs

```
using Azure.Core;
namespace TaxManagement.RestClient.Models
{
    [CodeGenModel("MessageBase")]
    public partial class MessageBaseTest { }
}
```

Then i run

`autorest --use:@autorest/csharp@3.0.0-beta.20210210.4  .\readme.md`

and nothing has changed in Generated/MessageBase.cs.
I also tried it in sample repo. However, the result was the same.
https://github.com/Azure/autorest.csharp/tree/feature/v3/samples/Azure.Storage.Tables